# Сортировка выбором не работает

Tags: python, алгоритм, сортировка

Имеется алгоритм сортировки выбором

```
def findMin(array):
    min = array[0]
    min_index = 0
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if array[i] < min:
            min_index = i
    return min_index

def sort(array):
    sorted_array = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        index = findMin(array)
        sorted_array.append(array.pop(index))
    return sorted_array

array = [2, 100, 3, 7, 100, 4, 9568]

array = sort(array)
print(array)
```

Однако я получаю неожиданный результат

```
[2, 4, 7, 3, 100, 100, 9568]
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в функции `findMin`после нахождения меньшего элемента вы не обновляете переменную `min`

```
def findMin(array):
    min = array[0]
    min_index = 0
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if array[i] < min:
            min_index = i
            min = array[i]
    return min_index
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо. Извиняюсь за невнимательность.

Answer (score 0):

используй лучше такой метод сортировки

```
def sort(array):
    for i in range(len(array) - 1):
        m = i
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(array):
            if array[j] < array[m]:
                m = j
            j = j + 1
        array[i], array[m] = array[m], array[i]
```

Comment: Я знаю, что сортировка выбором не является эффективной, решил использовать ее исключительно для ознакомления.

Comment: @Monsta Это тоже сортировка выбором